# php - file uploads using uploadify

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, uploadify

I'm having problems with uploadify. Whenever I use a string in the $post_id, uploadify only uploads a single file when I've selected 3 files for upload.
But when I specify a non-existing value for $post_id such as a session variable that doesn't exist $_SESSION['something']. It inserts all three of the files into the database. I'm thinking that this might be an error on the data structure of $post_id.

```
 if(!empty($_FILES)){
            $post_id = 'aa';
            $name2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
            $mime2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['Filedata']['type']);
            $data2 = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']));
            $size2 = intval($_FILES['Filedata']['size']);



            $db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_files SET post_id='$post_id', filename='$name2', file_data='$data2', mime_type_id='$mime2'");



    }
```

I tried to echo the rest of the data and it seems like they're only storing plain strings. So $post_id string should also work,

```
echo $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
```

Comment: $post_id is a PRIMARY KEY right, so insert rest of the fields alone not the $post_id

Comment: no, the post id is a foreign key. Its the id of the post from which the file was attached. Like the relation between an email and attachments.

Comment: what is $post_id? Do you get the post_id from uploadify function call

Comment: post id is stored in a session variable I have session auto started in php.ini . Do I need to pass it to uploadify function call to access it?How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this it should work as you expected**

```
 $tblQry = 'INSERT INTO tbl_files ';
 $tblQry .= 'SET         
        post_id                 = "' .$_SESSION['post_id'] . '",
        filename                = "' .$name2. '",
        file_data               = "' .$data2.'",
        mime_type_id            = "' .$mime2.'"';
  $db->query($tblQry);
```

Comment: unfortunately it still won't work. This is getting really annoying, it should already work. I mean why would a session that can be accessed on another php file not work on another, really weird. This might be a bug on uploadify.

Comment: use session_start(); at the top of this file

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sessions, please check that you have started session i.e session_start()

If you want to pass the post_id from uploadify function to php file, you can use the scriptData, which is mentioned in the below function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //uploadify function
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'uploader': 'uploadify.swf',
        'script': 'uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg': 'cancel.png',
        'folder': 'photos', //folder where images to be uploaded
        'auto': false, // use for auto upload
        'multi': true,
        'queueSizeLimit': 6,
        'buttonImg': 'images/upload.png',
        'width': '106',
        'height': '33',
        'wmode': 'transparent',
        'method': 'POST',
        'scriptData': {'myid':post_id}, //you can post the id here
        'onQueueFull': function(event, queueSizeLimit) {
            alert("Please don't put anymore files in me! You can upload " + queueSizeLimit + " files at once");
            return false;
        },
        'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
            $("#uploadfiles").append(response+",");
        },
        'onAllComplete': function(response, data) {
            showAll();
        }
    });
</script>
```

**uploadify.php**

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $post_id = $_POST['myid'];
    include_once "config.php";

    //use this when uploading images into a folder
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];

    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';

    $fna = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $fna;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    //folder upload end

           $name2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
            $mime2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['Filedata']['type']);
            $data2 = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']));
            $size2 = intval($_FILES['Filedata']['size']);



        $db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_files SET post_id='$post_id', filename='$name2', file_data='$data2', mime_type_id='$mime2'");

}
```

Comment: this might work but I'll only know the value that I'm going to post once I've posted to the primary table. I'm going to use the last inserted id as the value. This might work if I can post things only when I call the uploadifyUpload() function, because that's the only time that I have access to the value that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this problem. Flash doesn't use the cookies that are set in your browser so you need to pass your session id into the flash script as a post variable and then set the cookie value from the post value in your upload.php script. See:

[jQuery and Uploadify session in the php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158603/jquery-and-uploadify-session-in-the-php-file)