# Multiple File Upload PHP Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I am looking for a ajax php uploader to uploads multiple files , i found some but unfortunately they did not work successfully with IE because IE 7 & 8 did not support
HTML5.

Uploadify & Plupload works fine with flash in IE but they did not return anything after uploading the file.In response i want the modified file name because before uploading a file i will modify the file name.

Any help or suggestion would be highly appriciated.

Thanks
Gaurav

Comment: And read the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) on how to ask questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link for multiple file uploads using uploadify [php - file uploads using uploadify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717818/php-file-uploads-using-uploadify/9718294#9718294)

and in that link(in uploadify.php) replace the line

```
$fna = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
```

with

```
$fna = "your modified new filename";
```

Comment: hello nithi thanks for your response , do $fna variable returned back to flash script.I did not see any return of $fna to flash file.I want this modified file name onComplete event so that i can show the user image back from server.

Comment: if you want the new filename returned back, echo $fna in uploadify.php. Also add an hidden element with id as uploadfiles(in function calling file). If so, the response(uploaded filenames) will be appended to that hidden element by comma separated.

Comment: Hello nithi i did not got "in function calling file" to add the hidden element.Do you mean to add the hidden field with id "uploadfiles" in the same div we called uplodify.